# Disabled submit button not enabling with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added this JQuery - found on SO to validate my form so that fields must be filled before the submit button can be clicked, but the button never un-disables.

**Form**

```
<form action="homepage.php" method="POST" id="form">

<div class="medium-50 columns">
<label>Phone Number</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number" name="phone" />
</div>

<input type="submit" id="register" value="Submit" name="submit" disabled="disabled">

</form>
```

**JQuery**

```
(function() {
    $('form > input').keyup(function() {

        var empty = false;
        $('form > input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
})()
```

What is wrong?

Comment: isn't it `$('#register').attr('disabled',true);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because 'input' isn't a child of 'form'.

Take a look [here](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) and [here](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/).

Try this:

```js
(function() {
    $('form input').keyup(function() {
        
        var empty = false;
        
        $('form input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
        });
        console.log(empty);
      
        if (empty) {
            $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="homepage.php" method="POST" id="form">

<div class="medium-50 columns">
<label>Phone Number</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number" name="phone" />
</div>

<input type="submit" id="register" value="Submit" name="submit" disabled="disabled">
```

Comment: This works, as it should, however I should have described me requirement slightly better. On my form I have a group of checkboxes/radio buttons that are allowed to be left blank and then I have the form with input text boxes which have to be filled in. when I use this answer on mine it does not un disable still - i believe because of the checkboxes